# custom beautiful time slider

Tags: ios, time, slider, controls

Does anybody know how to make this kind of slider?
Maybe this is an open-source or apple standard control?

[Time Slider](http://www.pinterest.com/pin/314126142732571601/)

[image: Time Slider]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeline control you're looking for is not a standard Apple control. It seems that the timeline is from an app called [5COINS](http://5coins.cmsight.com/) developed by Zhu Yuzhou. The author has multiple open source repositories on [Github](https://github.com/codingrhythm) but he has not open sourced this particular timeline control. I'd recommend contacting the developer of 5COINS if you're still interested in implementing the control.